# Is there a convenient way to wrap a bash command list into rlwrap?

Tags: bash, command-line, line-editor

Thanks to a [question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/382401/75704), I found out about this utterly convenient `rlwrap` tool.

It satisfies my needs (i.e. add command history to another cmdline tool), but I was wondering how I can use it to add command history to a 'compound' shell command, like the prototypical

```
$> while read line; do echo "i read $line"; done
hi
i read hi
^D
```

When I put the `while` loop inside a shell script, and execute it like `rlwrap ./whilereadline.sh`, it's ok.

But I'm wondering how I can do this *without* the need for an additional file, somewhat like

```
$> rlwrap (while read line; do echo "line: $line"; done)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried

```
rlwrap sh -c 'while read line; do echo "i read $line"; done'
```

`rlwrap` needs a command it can run, which a `()` syntax-induced subshell is not.  `sh -c ...` is a command however.  Replace `sh` with `bash` or whatever shell you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

`rlwrap` needs a program to execute, it can't interpret the commands itself. You can wrap the shell code you want in a `bash -c` command:

```
rlwrap bash -c 'while read line; do echo "line: $line"; done'
```

Note that depending on what code you want to use for this, the quoting could become somewhat ugly.